# How to have 2 different XSD elements to be of same value if they are present

Tags: xml, xsd

I've an XSD file which has two separate complex type elements ( say `elemOne` and `elemTwo` ) which could store a common element ( say `elementRefer` ) of type `xs:string`. But I want my XML to store the common element `elementRefer` in either of the two complex type elements or both provided they both point to the same value of `elementRefer`.

How do I make this kind of restriction in XSD?? Could someone please help me out on this..

```
<root>
  <sample1>
    <name>johnson</name>
    <city>california</city>   <!-- optional occurence element-->
  </sample1>
  <sample2>
    <name>andrew</name>
    <age>19</age>
    <city>california</city>   <!-- optional occurence element-->
  </sample2>
</root>
```

Now I want to create a constraint in XSD so that the tag `city` occurs
under either `sample1` or `sample2`or both provided they both have the same value.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible.

Using `xs:key` and `xs:keyref` you could define the element `city` as a key in one case and as a key reference in the other - forcing them to have the same value, but this works only if the key element is non-optional.